# Excel programming - how to add contents to new field based on contents of another

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know VBA and have been given a quick task to do this afternoon which I don't know how to do. Lets say I have data in this format

```
ColA           ColB                ColC

'Cat A'        'SubCat B'         'Tag1 / Tag 2 / Tag 3'
```

I Have to create a 4th column which contains data like this

Cat A > SubCat B > Tag1 | Cat A > SubCat B > Tag2 |  Cat A > SubCat B > Tag3

So this 4th column basically contains pipe separated list where is list item is a concatenation of the category, subcateory and tag . There is one list item for each tag. This is the minor complication

Would I have to do this in VBA or just excel functions? Sorry for being so useless but its not my area and I need some pointers :)

thanks a lot

Please note I cannot simply concatentate the columns. I have to get each of the values in column C (tag1, tag2 and tag 3) and then produce a concatentation for each of these tags. Then all of these concatentations need to go in the same cell separated by a pipe

Comment: You can achieve this by string concatenation without VBA. It is not clear though, how the first three columns looks like. Would you mind editing your question?

Comment: I can't just simply concatentate column C to column A abd B. I have to split column c into however many values it contains and then produce one concatenation for each

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can concatenate with separators in Excel as follows:

**=A1 & ">" & B1 & ">" & C1**

Comment: I can't just simply concatentate column C to column A abd B. I have to split column c into however many values it contains and then produce one concatenation for each. In the example in the question 3 column C has 3 values which i have to split

Answer (score 0):

Put the function listed below to an VBA module and you can use it as a normal Worksheet Function.

```
= SOUser(A1, B1, C1)
```

VBA code:

```
Public Function SOUser(ByVal ColA As String, ByVal ColB As String, ByVal ColC As String) As String

  Dim aColC() As String
  Dim iCount As Integer
  Dim sRetVal As String

  aColC = Split(ColC, "/")

  For iCount = LBound(aColC) To UBound(aColC)
    If sRetVal = "" Then
      sRetVal = ColA & " > " & ColB & " > " & aColC(iCount)
    Else
      sRetVal = sRetVal & " | " & ColA & " > " & ColB & " > " & aColC(iCount)
    End If
  Next

  SOUser = sRetVal

End Function
```